# File locations Javascript vs Stylesheet in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

In a new default Rails 7 application using the import maps functionality, Javascript is stored in `app/javascript`, while CSS is located in `app/assets/stylesheets`. Not only are they located at different hierarchy levels, but `javascript` is singular, while `stylesheets` is plural.

I'm looking for sources that explain these divergent locations and pluralization decisions. Searches through [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) and [API documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) have turned up nothing, but support talk on the [Rails repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues) suggests that docs are still being actively updated.

On the surface this seems really shortsighted, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something before I go messing with the defaults.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`app/assets` is used by *sprockets*. This is *rails* asset pipeline. Preprocessing, minification, compilation etc. *app/assets/javascripts* was a thing before javascript took over the world and had to be given its own separate directory.

`app/javascript` was used by *webpacker* to avoid mixing it with *sprockets* processing. This is *javascript* pipeline that does what *sprockets* does, process, compile, minify etc. A way to bring javascript build tools into *rails*. Singular "javascript" is referring to Javascript language, not "javascripts" as in collection of js files.

Both of these directories can have css and js assets, just processed and compiled by different tools.

In *rails* 7, `app/javascript` is used by *jsbundling-rails* which integrates a few js build tools with *rails*: *esbuild*, *webpack*, and *rollup.js*. After javascript has done its job, bundles go into `app/assets/builds` where *sprockets* treats it as any other js or css file.

With *import-maps* there is no processing but `app/javascript` is the logical place for it. All files in *app/javascript* have to be precompiled by *sprockets* for use in production:

```js
// app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= ../../javascript .js
```

and *app/javascript* has to be in `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app/javascript")
```

This is what `importmap-rails` [does](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/blob/v1.2.1/lib/importmap/engine.rb#L47), among other things. Note that because *app/javascript* is added to `config.assets.paths`, it is part of *sprockets* pipeline from the start.

Here is a short overview of who lives where:

```
app/
├─ assets/          # used by sprockets-rails, propshaft, everything else hooks into it
│  ├─ build/        # compiled assets (jsbundling-rails, cssbundling-rails, tailwindcss-rails)
│  ├─ config/       # precompile `build/` if any of these three ^ are used
│  │                #  and precompile `app/javascript/` if importmap-rails is used
│  ├─ stylesheets/  # used by cssbundling-rails, tailwindcss-rails
│  └─ javascripts/  # not used in rails 7 by default, but any directory can be added to `app/assets/`,
│                   #  just add it to config/manifest.js as well 
└─ javascript/      # used by jsbundling-rails, importmap-rails and anything node related
   └─ controllers/  # used by stimulus-rails
```

Also, rails gems themselves use `app/assets/javascripts` to ship any js files so that you have access to them via asset [url](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) and [tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) helpers.