# Issue with setting up actioncable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, actioncable, rails-api

My project is set up as rails only API application, and flagged with no javascript. they have added active admin to it and made necessary changes to it making javascripts folder in assets as required by active admin. now i need to add actioncable functionality along with chat for it. for user side it is fine as we are using react front-end. but for admin i need to implement actioncable to push messages in real time to browser. how can i set it up. I have even tried with importmap-rails.
ruby- 2.6.5
rails -6.0.6.1

my approach was I tried to create a chat_channel.js in app/assests/javascripts/channels and added following snipped and added a javascript_include_tag as module in required page-view from admin

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("ChatChannel", {
  connected() {
    console.log("Connected to the chat channel.");
  },

  disconnected() {
    console.log("Disconnected from the chat channel.");
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log("Received message:", data.message);
    // Handle the received message here
  }
});
```

my consumer.js file has

```
import { createConsumer } from "@rails/actioncable"

const consumer = createConsumer()

export default consumer
```

error i am facing when it is loaded
`load_messages:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@rails/actioncable". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

there is no package.json file at the starting, but as tried to do so with npm install and add actioncable. but none of them worked.

i got it i am unable to load modules properly. i tried npm i @rails/actioncable, or yarn add @rails/actioncable. those things didnt help. i tried with impotmaps-rails following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73347704/how-to-set-up-actioncable-with-importmaps-in-rails-6-mri-and-jruby). as this has similarities with my case.this also ended with same error.

Comment: Same error.  I got it to work by running `bin/importmap pin @rails/actioncable` in the Rails home directory.